# Внутреннее строение функций в C

Tags: c

Вопрос банальный, но я не могу понять. Когда изучал java, чтобы посмотреть как устроена та или иная функция мне было достаточно нажать на Ctrl + лкм на нужную функцию и сразу можно было посмотреть ее реализацию в стандарте. А как это делать на C? Делаю тоже самое, но вместо ее реализации вылетают различные #define, в которых ничего толком и нет.

Comment: Качаете исходники и читаете их

Comment: @avp а где их скачать не подскажите?

Comment: https://code.woboq.org

Comment: [Одна из реализаций libc](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src) (написана без излишних усложнений)